# Fastest way to count number of rows in MySQL database in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, count, laravel

I can think of a couple ways to count the number of rows in a table with Laravel (version 3).

```
DB::table('threads')->count();
Threads::count();
Threads::max('id');
DB::table('threads')->max('id);
DB::query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM threads;');
```

Are any of these notably faster than the others? Is there any one fastest way to run this query? Later on it's going to be part of an expression: `ceil(DB::table('threads')->count() / $threads_per_page);` and it's executed on every page load so it's good to be optimized.

Database/table is MySQL and the InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAX(ID) is not the same as counting rows, so that rules out two of five alternatives.

And then it is your task to actually do a performance comparison between the remaining three methods to get the count. I'd think that actually executing an SQL statement directly might remove plenty of unnecessary ORM-layer overhead and be actually faster, but this would be premature optimization unless proven by facts.

Comment: Good point on the `MAX(id)`, you are right. Right now I just go with `Threads::count()` but that seems like a lot of ORM bloat. I guess I'll have to test or something.

Comment: MAX(id) is showing the biggest id in your table. So if you delete rows, the number of entry in your table will not be the same as the biggest id.

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('threads')->count();
Threads::count();
DB::query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM threads;');
```

I was looking for the same thing.
These 3 results are exactly the same query I tested it (You can watch this with laravel debugbar).
Laravel perform "SELECT COUNT(*) as aggregate FROM threads";
It's already optimised with eloquent, but if you do ->get()->count() it's not optimised !
No performance difference with Threads::count();

Max('id') is totally different as it output the max id, it will never count the number of rows.

Answer (score -1):

i dont think that it really that matter.. just be consistent in your code..
any way there is no need to run that query on evey page load.. use some caching to cache that number..

Comment: The # changes rather frequently, so you basically do have to calculate it on every page load.